# $X$ $T_4$, then $X/R$ $T_4$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I found out that if $X$ is $T_4$ and $R$ is a closed equivalence relation, then $X/R$ is also $T_4$. I was just wondering whether the same is true for $R$ being an open equivalence relation?

Comment: By closed equivalence relation do you mean a relation which is closed as a subset of $X\times X$, or a relation such that the quotient map is closed?

Comment: the map shall be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no. If $q:I\to X$ is the quotient map collapsing $(0,1)$ to a point, then it's open, but $0$ and $1$ cannot be separated by neighborhoods in $X$.